# Laravel 5.5 Pagination response json return message: Method view does not exist status code 500

Tags: php, laravel, vue-tables-2

I am trying to get some json data from pagination laravel but the process returns with a status code 500 and gives a massage "Method [view] does not exist on [App\Http\Controllers\Api\ConsumerController]."

Here is my code api.php

```
Route::get('/consumer/view/paginate', 'Api\ConsumerController@paginate_consumer');
```

Here is my code ConsumerController on paginate_consumer method

```
public function paginate_consumer()
{
    $consumer = Consumer::paginate_consumer();

    return response()->json($consumer);
}
```

Here is my code model Consumer on method paginate_consumer()

```
public static function paginate_consumer()
{
    try{
        $consumer = Consumer::where('void', 0)->paginate();

        return $consumer;
    } catch(\Exception $e){
        var_dump($e->getMessage() . ' ' . $e->getFile() . ' ' . $e->getLine());
    }
}
```

My expectation is that I can return json data using pagination laravel. Can anyone help me?

Comment: That's not where this error is coming from. Do you have a route pointing to `ConsumerController@view`?

Comment: Oh i see. THANKKK YOUUUU I CAN HANDLE THAT, my problem is one of my code lines in api.php is wrong -____- @aynber. Thank you very much.